How to use a global $derived in Svelte 5?
I'm trying to create a global state with Svelte 5 and runes:
// store.svelte.ts
export const person = ({
    name: '',
});

export const mrName = $derived('Mr. ' + person.name); // <-- problem!

I can't make $derived to work:
Cannot export derived state from a module.

6 |  export const mrName = $derived("Mr. " + person.name);
                                                           ^
7 |

What's the correct approach to a global $derived?

In many cases you don't really need a $derived. If you export a function (or use an getter), it will also be reactive, the only difference would be that the value is potentially created multiple times even if the name did not change. Since this is not an expensive operation, it would not matter much.

Derived state in svelte.ts/svelte.ts files needs to be wrapped in a class or a function.
Class
You can use a constructor to set initial state, but that wasn't in your example, so I didn't include it here.
Classes add getters/setters for each property when it is compiled.
// store.svelte.ts
export class Person {
  name = $state('')
  mrName = $derived("Mr. " + this.name)
}

Reference: https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/$state#Classes
Function
Need to use get() to return the current state values from the function, otherwise it will only show the values at the time the function was initially called.
// store.svelte.ts
export const Person = () => {
  let name = $state('')
  let mrName = $derived("Mr. " + name)
  return {
    get name() { return name },
    get mrName() { return mrName }
  }
}

There was a reference for the get() requirement in the svelte 5 preview docs but haven't found it yet in the new docs.
